# Calling and executing another file in if statement

Tags: python, face-recognition, rfid

I’m currently using Pycharm.

I have two codes, one is for face recognition and the other is for reading information from the Arduino IDE.

The main idea of the project is that we’re going to read the RFID card and then we’re going to get the serial number and we will see if that serial number is approved or not. if the RFID card is recognized, it would move to face recognition.

Now what I want to do is that after executing the RFID code(if approved), I want it to read and execute the face recognition code.

Below are the codes

Reading from Arduino:

```
import serial
import time
import pandas as pd


device = 'COM6'
try:
    print("Connecting to device"), device
    arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600)
except:
    print("Failed to connect on"), device

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        data = arduino.readline()
        print(data)

        try:
            if data == b'213 237 169 54\r\n':
                print("Approved")

        except:
            print("no")

    except:
        print("Processing")
```

As for face recognition

```
import cv2
import pickle

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/Person/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/cascade/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("recognizer/training.yml")

labels = {}
with open("labels.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    og_labels = pickle.load(f)
    labels = {v: k for k, v in og_labels.items()}



cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        #print(x, y, w, h)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        id_, conf = recognizer.predict(roi_gray)
        if conf>=73 and conf <=100:
           # print(id_)
            print(labels[id_])
            print("face recognized")
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            name = labels[id_]
            color = (255, 255, 255)
            stroke = 2
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (x, y), font, 1, color, stroke, cv2.LINE_AA)



        img_item = "person.png"
        cv2.imwrite(img_item, roi_gray)

        color = (255, 0, 0)
        stroke = 2
        end_cord_x = x + w
        end_cord_y = y + h
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (end_cord_x, end_cord_y), color, stroke )



    cv2.imshow("Video Capture", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? So, if the RFID serial number is approved, I want it to execute the face recognition code.

Thank you!!

Comment: put both scripts in functions and then use the script as a module to import it in a main script and then run it sequentially. It is a matter of how you refactor your scripts

Comment: I'll try this now. Thank you

Comment: Wrap both methods in a function and import it from the other file and then you'll be able to call it